# Refreshing textbox output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, refresh

I have a simple decimal to binary converter.

It works simple, you write your decimal number in the textbox, and click on the button to get your outcome, but I want it to be automatic, so you don't have to click on the submit button everytime, and refreshes automatic.
My code is:

```
<div id="Conv" style="font:24px bold; display: none">
Decimaal naar binair.<br>
    <input type="text" id="txtDec" maxlength="3"/>
    <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="document.getElementById('Converter2').innerHTML=ConvertToBinary(document.getElementById('txtDec').value);" />
    <span id="Converter2"></span>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript part:

```
function ConvertToBinary(dec) {
    var bits = [];
    var dividend = dec;
    var remainder = 0;
    while (dividend >= 2) {
        remainder = dividend % 2;
        bits.push(remainder);
        dividend = (dividend - remainder) / 2;
    }
    bits.push(dividend);
    bits.reverse();

    return String('000000000' + bits.join("")).slice(-8);


}
```

Comment: you want to move the event of button in onchange/onkeyup event of txtDec

Comment: So, you've five decent answers here, any of provided answers is not worth of [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/about)?

Answer (score 0):

You could run the code **onkeyup**

```
<input type="text" id="txtDec" maxlength="3" onkeyup="convert(this)" />

function convert(el) {
    document.getElementById('Converter2').innerHTML=ConvertToBinary(el.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle Conversion in your textbox's `.keyup()` event

```
$('#txtDec').keyup(function(e) {
    var converted = ConvertToBinary(this.value);
    $('span#Converter2').text(converted);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .keyup() and change the value once user finishes the entry (aka press enter key)

```
$('#txtDec').keyup(function(event) {
     if (event.keyCode == 13){
        var converted = ConvertToBinary(this.value);
        $('span#Converter2').text(converted);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that proposed options are good enough in case this task is for studying javascript only. 
Otherwise let me add some general notes.
If you are working with standard form elements such as input and textarea you are able to insert text with the help of mouse(i mean right click -> paste). This way it is not enough to handle keyup only. 
Handle every mouse click with listening to mouseup is also not-so-good idea. What about changing field programmically?

I believe that the best way is to handle onchange event, that triggers each time you have changed inner value and element is going to be "unfocused".

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can use [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) event, which is triggered every time the content of the `input` is changed. In older browsers (practically IE<9) you can use [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) event, but in this case you need to blur the `input` before the event fires. (In IEs only, there's [`onpropertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event available, which can handle also programmatically made changes to an element.)

In the codesnippet below I've rewritten your `ConvertToBinary()` function, just to show an alternative way to convert the base of a number. [`Number.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) can be used to convert a decimal number to any base between 2 and 36, and [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) can be used to convert a string representing a number based between 2 and 36 to a decimal.

```
document.getElementById('txtDec').addEventListener('input', function () {
    var bin = parseInt(this.value, 10).toString(2),
        digits = ''; 
    if (!isNaN(bin) && bin.length < 9) {
        digits = new Array(9 - bin.length).join('0') + bin;
    }
    document.getElementById('Converter2').innerHTML = digits;
});
```

[**A live demo at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YwN4j/).

Ofcourse you can use your original `ConvertToBinary()` within the anonymous function passed to [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), or you can pass the name of it only:

```
document.getElementById('txtDec').addEventListener('input', ConvertToBinary);
```